# Generate short unique words

Tags: bash

I am looking for a way to generate a text file that contains as many unique words as possible while being as small as possible. Ideally it should look like this:

a b c ... aa ab ac ... aaa aab aac ... etc.

etc.

The words can contain numbers and ascii characters. My task is to generate a text file (<1MB) that overwhelmes a certain hash function, and although I know that such a file is the way to do it, I don't know how to generate such words. I tried using `base64 /dev/urandom | head -c`, but this only provides words of a set length.

I'm thankful for any help!

Edit: It seems like I definitely need ascii characters for this to work.

Comment: `echo {a..c}{a..c}{a..c}`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this script from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204087:

```
#!/bin/bash
charset=({a..z} {A..Z} {0..9})
permute(){
  (($1 == 0)) && { echo "$2"; return; }
  for char in "${charset[@]}"
  do
    permute "$((${1} - 1 ))" "$2$char"
  done
}
permute "$1"
```

Then combine the results from `./permute.sh 2`, `./permute.sh 3` and `./permute.sh 4`

### Edit

To add ascii characters, you can use the code from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/74542:

```
// Print all combinations of the given alphabet up to length n.
//
// The best way to test this program is to output to /dev/null, otherwise
// the file I/O will dominate the test time.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char *alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                       "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                       " \t,./;'[]\\-=`<>?:\"{}|~!@#$%^&*()_+"
                       "0123456789";

static void generate(int maxlen);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s Length\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    generate(atoi(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Generates all patterns of the alphabet up to maxlen in length.  This
 * function uses a buffer that holds alphaLen * alphaLen patterns at a time.
 * One pattern of length 5 would be "aaaaa\n".  The reason that alphaLen^2
 * patterns are used is because we prepopulate the buffer with the last 2
 * letters already set to all possible combinations.  So for example,
 * the buffer initially looks like "aaaaa\naaaab\naaaac\n ... aaa99\n".  Then
 * on every iteration, we write() the buffer out, and then increment the
 * third to last letter.  So on the first iteration, the buffer is modified
 * to look like "aabaa\naabab\naabac\n ... aab99\n".  This continues until
 * all combinations of letters are exhausted.
 */
static void generate(int maxlen)
{
    int   alphaLen = strlen(alphabet);
    int   len      = 0;
    char *buffer   = malloc((maxlen + 1) * alphaLen * alphaLen);
    int  *letters  = malloc(maxlen * sizeof(int));

    if (buffer == NULL || letters == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // This for loop generates all 1 letter patterns, then 2 letters, etc,
    // up to the given maxlen.
    for (len=1;len<=maxlen;len++) {
        // The stride is one larger than len because each line has a '\n'.
        int i;
        int stride = len+1;
        int bufLen = stride * alphaLen * alphaLen;

        if (len == 1) {
            // Special case.  The main algorithm hardcodes the last two
            // letters, so this case needs to be handled separately.
            int j = 0;
            bufLen = (len + 1) * alphaLen;
            for (i=0;i<alphaLen;i++) {
                buffer[j++] = alphabet[i];
                buffer[j++] = '\n';
            }
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, bufLen);
            continue;
        }

        // Initialize buffer to contain all first letters.
        memset(buffer, alphabet[0], bufLen);

        // Now write all the last 2 letters and newlines, which
        // will after this not change during the main algorithm.
        {
            // Let0 is the 2nd to last letter.  Let1 is the last letter.
            int let0 = 0;
            int let1 = 0;
            for (i=len-2;i<bufLen;i+=stride) {
                buffer[i]   = alphabet[let0];
                buffer[i+1] = alphabet[let1++];
                buffer[i+2] = '\n';
                if (let1 == alphaLen) {
                    let1 = 0;
                    let0++;
                    if (let0 == alphaLen)
                        let0 = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        // Write the first sequence out.
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, bufLen);

        // Special case for length 2, we're already done.
        if (len == 2)
            continue;

        // Set all the letters to 0.
        for (i=0;i<len;i++)
            letters[i] = 0;

        // Now on each iteration, increment the the third to last letter.
        i = len-3;
        do {
            char c;
            int  j;

            // Increment this letter.
            letters[i]++;

            // Handle wraparound.
            if (letters[i] >= alphaLen)
                letters[i] = 0;

            // Set this letter in the proper places in the buffer.
            c = alphabet[letters[i]];
            for (j=i;j<bufLen;j+=stride)
                buffer[j] = c;

            if (letters[i] != 0) {
                // No wraparound, so we finally finished incrementing.
                // Write out this set.  Reset i back to third to last letter.
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, bufLen);
                i = len - 3;
                continue;
            }

            // The letter wrapped around ("carried").  Set up to increment
            // the next letter on the left.
            i--;
            // If we carried past last letter, we're done with this
            // whole length.
            if (i < 0)
                break;
        } while(1);
    }

    // Clean up.
    free(letters);
    free(buffer);
}
```

Save this code to a file called "permute.c", then compile the code with `gcc -Wall -O3 -o permute_all_chars permute.c` and run `./permute_all_chars 3 > words.txt` to get a 3.4M file of unique words. If you need a larger file, use `./permute_all_chars 4 > words.txt` (408M) and so on.

Comment: Would there be any way to include ascii characters in this? I believe I do need them to be able to do what I want.

Comment: Thank you, this turned out to be exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

If `python` happens to be your option, would you please try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import string
import itertools

s = string.digits + string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation
for i in itertools.product(s, repeat=2):
    print(''.join(i))
```

- The variable `s` consists of 94 characters: digits, upper & lower alphabets
  and punctuation characters.
- The `itertools.product()` function generates the products of the characters
  in `s` of the length specified by `repeat=n`. If you set the repeat number
  to 2, it will generate the words such as: `00`, `01`, `02` ...
  The count of words will be 94 * 94 = 8,836.
- If you want to generate more words, modify the repeat number to `3`.
  Then it will produce 830,584 words.